# How does AdamW weight_decay works for L2 regularization?

Tags: python, regularization

hello I have a question about weight regularization in Adam
apparently the `weight_decay` in the AdamW function https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/optimizer_schedules.html#adamw-pytorch has the same impact as an `L2 regularization`

my questions are: is that parameter the same as `lambda` that we have in the `regularization term`?

[L2 regularization formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIp2m.png)

how does it exactly work? and what is its impact on the model complexity?

Comment: Everything is explained in https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.05101.
PyTorch used AdamW, as well some other libraries at this moment.
FastAi was the first library implementing [AdamW](https://www.fast.ai/2018/07/02/adam-weight-decay/). Your question has been answered in [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3407).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> apparently the weight_decay in the AdamW function [...] has the same impact as an L2 regularization

This claim isn't entirely correct. Both of these regularization techniques are conceptually, but they aren't the same in the case of adaptive gradient algorithms.

In fact, the [AdamW paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.05101.pdf) begins by stating:

> L2 regularization  and  weight  decay  regularization  are  equivalent  for  standard stochastic gradient descent (when rescaled by the learning rate), but as we demonstrate this is not the case for adaptive gradient algorithms, such as Adam.

For more information about how it works I suggest you read the paper.